# Executing process on Linux from WSGI based web application

Tags: linux, wsgi

I have a dashboard and I want a process to run when the user clicks on a button. That process might take a long time to complete.

My options so far:

1. using popen or something similar to execute the process
2. having a daemon monitor a directory. When this directory is changed (a file created) the daemon will do the job and then delete the file before idling again.
3. using cron, running every 5 seconds and also monitoring some directory.

Which one is more Linux-friendly? Is there any I have not considered?

Comment: [celery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/celery)

Comment: Looks promising, but a bit overkilling in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what task queueing systems like Celery and Redis Queue are for.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to have a daemon (as in your 2nd option) that listen on some socket.  Then, your WSGI application could just connect & send a command.  There are many possibilities for how the communication over the socket would take place, choosing the right one depends a lot on the actual case.

This have the advantage that you can eventually have the two application (WSGI and the daemon) run on different computers or VMs at some point.